# NodeJS + Typescript - Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: node.js, typescript

`@Table({ tableName: 'profiles' })`
`export class Profile extends Model<Profile> {`
`@Column({ type: DataType.UUID, defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4 })`
`uuid_profile!: string;`

```
@Column({ type: DataType.STRING })
name_profile!: string;

@Column({ type: DataType.DATE, defaultValue: DataType.DATE })
created!: Date;
```

`}`

I am getting the error

C:\projetos\digielevate-admin-back\src\models\Profile.ts:13     created!: Date;                                        ^ TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object     at Function.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (<anonymous>)     at C:\projetos\digielevate-admin-back\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\model\column\column.js:18:131     at __esDecorate (C:\projetos\digielevate-admin-back\src\models\Profile.ts:13:40)     at C:\projetos\digielevate-admin-back\src\models\Profile.ts:7:5     at C:\projetos\digielevate-admin-back\src\models\Profile.ts:81:7     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projetos\digielevate-admin-back\src\models\Profile.ts:83:3)     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)     at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\karin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)     at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\karin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)

can anybody help me? I'm still new to NodeJs with Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's mostly due to default value that you are trying to set, try this and let me know.

```
@Column({ type: DataType.DATE, defaultValue: () => new Date() })
created!: Date;
```

Comment: I still have the same error. I've tried without default value too